# How should I restart spring in Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spring, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm going through the [Agile Web Development with Rails 6](https://pragprog.com/book/rails6/agile-web-development-with-rails-6) book and I got to the end of an "Iteration" and did `bin/rails test` and got a horrible long ugly dump somewhere in fixtures.  (I'm not new to Rails ... just trying to catch up on all the new toys in Rails 6 and refresh).

I made sure all my code matched the sample code and then finally did `ps -ef | grep -i spring` and found three processes -- one of the 24 hours old.  I killed them with just `kill <pid>` and then did `bin/rails test` and all was fine.

I realize that "in theory" I am not suppose to need to tell `spring` to restart but obviously sometimes you do.  So, what is the prescribed method for restarting `spring`?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

To stop spring you can use `bin/spring stop`. It should start automatically when you run rails commands.